# Haskell type signatures: Question on type signature of lastButOne Program

Tags: haskell, types

I'm reading through *Real World Haskell* and one of the exercises is to construct a function lastButOne, which simply returns the second to last element of a list.

My code so far:

```
lastButOne xs = if null xs || length xs == 1
                    then []
                else if length xs == 2
                    then head xs
                else lastButOne (tail xs)
```

**My problem**:
The input *should* be a list, which then returns an empty list if it is either nonempty or is of length 1, and in other cases returns the second to last element. However, I get an error when I input a list. I don't get any errors when I input a second order nested list.

I suspected something was wrong with the type signature, and when I call the type signature, it returns

```
lastButOne :: [[a]] -> [a].
```

But I want the type signature to be `[a] -> a`. I've stared at this function for a while and have explored other posts, but I can't seem to figure out why the type signature is `[[a]] -> a`. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: your function as it stands can return either `[]` or an element of the input list - and these therefore must have the same type. (I suspect the exercise doesn't intend for you to handle the error cases - and I don't think there's a good way to handle them other than using `Maybe`, which you may not have learned about yet.)

Comment: Oh I see my error. I fixed it by all together returning ```head xs``` when ```length xs <= 2```. 

But ideally, I would want to somehow treat the case of an empty list or a singleton list differently--if this were python, perhaps I would print an error message or something. But I can't really do that in Haskell; if I want to treat these cases differently, I must return something of type ```a``` if the input is of type ```[a]```. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: You could make it a runtime error, but a function of type `[a] -> Maybe a` is more appropriate. "Short" lists return `Nothing`; longer lists return `Just x` (where `x` is the appropriate value from the list).

Comment: @trujello, `head` in the prelude raises a runtime error if the list is empty.  People don't like it very much, but until you learn a better technique it's okay.  You can just say e.g. `error "List was empty"`.

Comment: @luqui I understand, thanks so much!

Comment: As a general thumb rule, if you are using any of `head, tail, !!` you should consider using pattern matching instead -- those functions can easily crash your program on wrong input, when (exhaustive) pattern matching never does. Instead `length list == constant` never crashes, but is usually inefficient, since it scans the whole list when only the first elements would suffice -- again, pattern matching is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can acomplish that with pattern matching like:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
lastButOne []    = error "not elements"
lastButOne [x]   = x
lastButOne [x,_] = x
lastButOne (x:xs) = lastButOne xs
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner in Haskell; could you clarify on what you mean here, i.e., on pattern matching?

Comment: @trujello, pattern matching is the name given to this style of definition, where you give multiple equations for a function you are defining.  The first one says what to do when it is given an empty list, the second one when given a list with one element, and so on.  [read more here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)

Comment: I'm not completely convinced the OP wants `lastButOne [x] = x` instead of being an error. (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You may explicitly declare your function's type signature by adding `lastButOne :: [a] -> [a]` to your code. The function will then expect xs to be a list.

But then we would meet another error: the fact that one of the outputs of your function (`head xs`) isn't in fact a list `[a]`, but rather an element `a`.

A similar error message will pop up if you add the signature `lastButOne :: [a] -> a`, but this time because `[]` is not an element of type `a`.

A simple solution might be to return your second to last element inside a list, using `[head xs]` as an output.